# Why path isn't added to sys.path

Tags: python, path

I have such structure of project:

```
Project:
    __init_.py
    sub_pack1:
        __init__.py
        x.py
        y.py
    sub_pack2
        __init__.py
        main.py
```

I launch `main.py` and it imports `sub_pack1.x`. This importing works fine. But when I do `import y` inside `x.py` I get an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'y'
```

I do `print(sys.path)` inside `x.py` and doesn't find `Project/sub_pack1/`  directory. Why so? How to overcome this problem (do correct `import y` in x.py)?

P.S python version is 3.6

Comment: which version of python? you're inside a module (not on the path; guessing Project is on the path?), so you probably want `from . import y`...